# angular ui bootstrap modal opened in state, how to close in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi there I am trying to create stateful modals, using ui-router and ui-bootstrap, I have the modal opening successfully like this,

```
.state('static.login', {
        url: '^/login',
        onEnter: function($modal, $state, $stateParams) {
            var modalInstance;
            modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation : false,
                templateUrl : 'app/components/login/views/login.view.html',
                controller : 'loginController',
                size : 'lg'
            });
            return modalInstance.result["finally"](function() {
                return $state.go('^');
            });
        }
        // templateUrl: 'app/components/login/views/login.view.html',
        // controller: 'loginController'
    })
```

But I am struggling to close the modal from my loginController, I thought it would be a simple of case of running `$modal.dismiss('cancel')` but I get told that dismiss is undefined function, do I need to do something else to be able to close my modal from my controller?

Also when ever I navigate to /login the homepage shows below the modal, it would be great if I keep the current page below it, is this possible?

Comment: One way is to open it through a service and share the service with controller. Store the modalInstance object in service

Comment: Open it in the controller as an activate function.. And you can close it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Once you open a modal, inside modal controller i.e. `loginController` you can see `$modalInstance` service which will take hold of modal instance.

There you could inject and use `$modalInstance` service inside `loginController`

And for closing popup you could close method over `$modalInstance`

```
app.controller('loginController', function($modalInstance){

   //..other controller code which you already had

   //for closing popup do below
   $modalInstance.close();

});
```